# How to fetch google classroom api's announcements in "swift".

Tags: google-classroom

I can get the course list of particular student by signin with the student's credential.

private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeClassroomCourses],

but i need the kGTLRAuthScopeClassroomAnnouncements and have to query using the let query = GTLRClassroomQuery_Announcement.query().

But it is not available for swift classes it seems,

how to get that? Ur help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a R&D of the client api,the library which is already built in objective C was the clue. I was checking for announcements in that, unfortunately it was missing in my library. So i changed the files which i separately downloaded. Now i got the announcements and also the query. It made me look into the library files deeper.